# What happens if I click "automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Tags: support, comments, chat

Does it for example automatically move all the comments between me and the other guy, both mine and his, or it lets me decide which, singular, ones to move?

I don't want to try it because there are a couple comments of the discussion that could be moved to the chat, but most definitely not all, so I don't want to risk losing all that useful stuff just to try a feature.

I couldn't find anything about it in the help or in previous questions.

Comment: I believe it copies them all to chat, but doesn't remove them from the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93086/discussion-between-gbr-and-deduplicator).

Comment: Great, apparently they are only copied. I'd like to have some official word though, especially sinces "move" usually means "move", not copy

Comment: And it looks estremely suspicious to me, Stack Exchange that doesn't take an excellent occasion to delete stuff? Maybe only useful stuff gets deleted/blocked/lapidated, butchered and thrown in an acid bath :)

Comment: The *discussion* is moved from the comments to a chat-room. There is nothing to indicate that the *comments themselves* should be moved. I guess it the original message-author had thought it would be confusing, they'd have chosen some other phrasing.

Comment: @BillWoodger ohh come on.. because they can't make mistakes and never did...

Comment: @BillWoodger To _automatically move_ a discussion would probably require some mechanism that forces the two parties to only discuss in the new place, through some form of mind control or such (the concept of discussion you use seem to imply that it is an _ongoing_ discussion)

Answer (score 13):

I've been in that situation more than once and can report that the comments get copied, not moved.

Maybe you want to post a feature request saying that you want them to be moved, not copied or the text be changed.

Comment: Well I'd rather ask that the message be changed, from 'moved' to 'copied'. It is a rather sane design as it is, message aside.

Comment: I'll wait a little more if I hear from someone that does know the source code and can guarantee that they always behave this way (and does not get really removed after a while), otherwise I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @gbr I do not know the source code but I dare guarantee you that it always behaves like this. You want the comments to be copied to chat to have the context available there, but you don't want them removed from the question, because they might hold valuable information.

Comment: @gbr: FWIW, once I "continue this discussion in chat" I usually clean up the extraneous comments on the original page, to make it look neater, since I know that there will be a permanent record of everything in the Chat.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Well context and valuable information is deleted all the time on stack exchange, in my experience... It''s that indeed that makes it even stranger that this one thing that could be expected to delete stuff (although keeping a copy of it in the chat) doesn't. There seems to be a wicked intentional design behind this... :D

Comment: @gbr *context and valuable information is deleted all the time* - context is very broad. Some context is good (problem related), some is not (hi guys i work at company X and i have Y years of programming experience bla bla). Valuable information is rarely deleted, and if it is, we try to make sure it gets undeleted.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I had guessed that the intent was for something like that to happen (but I feared it might happen on the part of moderators as well)

Comment: @TimCastelijns _Valuable information is rarely deleted, and if it is, we try to make sure it gets undeleted_ 
not really my experience, anyhow that's off-topic

Comment: @PM 2Ring - there won't be a permanent record, as far as I know, the rooms stays open for 7 days or so after the last activity. I made use of the feature some weeks ago and that room is gone (which is okay, we just used it to do some bug hunting)

Comment: @TimCastelijns I saw a large swath of important comments (some of which took me hours to write) get nuked just a few hours ago, by who knows who and for what reason

Comment: @gbr: I've been where you are. If you are expecting your comments to be permanent on SO; you will have a bad experience. Even [questions and answers are deleted sometimes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/137096). See [Who can delete comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/137096)

Answer (score -16):

It doesn't matter what it does, because you should never use that misfeature.

The discussion of a question belongs next to the question -- that is, in the comments on the question.

Comment: Given the choice, I'd turn off the link - I know it pops up when we're _having a discussion_  but I'm never going to join chat to continue it.

Comment: I use chat when debugging is going back and forth too much. It adds nothing to the answer until those small details can be hashed out and which point the relevant details can be added to the answer. Keeps the comments cleaner as well. For instance when the op is posting a mcve but testing in his real environment.

Comment: @Matt You should do that in the comments.  "Clean comments" is not a thing you should want.

Comment: Yes but as you know comments are second class citizens and should add nothing to the answer itself else they would be there already. No need to distract from the answer if there is no value whatsoever

Comment: @Matt Comments should not be second class citizens, and everyone who endorses their second-class-ness is wrong.

Comment: Second class does not mean worthless. It is just that if there is important content it should be part of the post so as to not risk its loss. Some users only read the answer and not the accompanying comments.

Comment: _"everyone who endorses their second-class-ness is wrong"_ -- No, actually you could not be more wrong yourself. From [the "comment" documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/comments/info) itself: _"Comments are second-class citizens"_. You may dispute their status here from a feature-request/policy-change point of view, but there is no question that the _current_ treatment of comments on Stack Overflow is as second-class citizens.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "Disputing their status here" is exactly what I am doing. I am very much aware that the community consensus and the current site design treat comments as second class. I think that that is wrong, and I think everyone who disagrees with me on that point is wrong.

Comment: Good luck with that, Mr. Quixote.